# Compound nouns with singular verb

Tags: nouns, verb-agreement, compounds, coordinating-conjunctions

Do you consider the subject in the following to be compound, justifying a singular verb?

"His impact and influence is undeniable."

On the one hand, the nouns do not form a common phrase; on the other hand, they have a similar meaning so might be considered a unit. What are you views? And do you know if usage is shifting?

Comment: ...in your case I think it's effectively a stylistic choice (i.e. - whether you consider "impact and influence" to represent a single pairing of two intertwined concepts/attributes, or two completely different things). I see nothing wrong with these written instances of [*his honesty and fairness **is** (known to all)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+honesty+and+fairness+is%22), for example.